# Confusion about Flow Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

I am asked to calculate the flow integral $$\int{\vec{F}\cdot\hat{T}ds}$$

of $\vec{F}=<2x,-3y>$ along the fourth quadrant path from (5,-3) to (8,0) along the curve $x^2-10x+y^2+16=0$.

So I need to parameterize the curve and I can calculate the integral by the formula $$\int{\vec{F}\cdot\hat{T}ds}=\int{\vec{F}\cdot{d}\vec{r}}$$

where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector.

For the life of me I can't remember how to parameterize a curve such as that into vector form.

Is this the correct process that I should be taking?  And how do I parameterize the curve?

Comment: $\{x^2-10x+y^2+16=0\}=\{(x-5)^2+y^2-9=0\}$ is a circle with radius $3$, centered in $(5,0)$...

Comment: Ah ok, great!  Thank you. I think I've got it. Although I am wondering about my bounds.  I believe we need $cos(\theta)$ to go from 0 to 1, but there are multiple values of $\theta$ that can achieve this.  So are the theta values dictated by the fact we are in the fourth quadrant?

Comment: To find the right range of $\theta$, try drawing where $(5,0),\ (5,-3),\ (8,0)$ are.

Comment: Ok yea, that's pretty much what I did.  I believe that $\theta$ runs from ${3{\pi}}/2$ to $2\pi$.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Comment: Ok great, I really appreciate your help.